# Moving more than 1 object with just 1 script in unity /2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I know we can move objects by adding scripts into that objects in unity. But i am curious about something else. How can we create a script that updates all game world (imports all objects and updates their position with every timer tick). How can we import that objects into that script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally done the other way around- the 'move' script is attached to desired objects to move.

However, a couple of ways you can get reference to several objects from the script are:

GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(GameObject);

OR

GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Untagged");  //returns GameObject[]

Source: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/329395/how-to-get-all-gameobjects-in-scene.html

Comment: Thank you. That is the answer i was looking for :)

Comment: One more question. Where should i put that script that moves game objects with every timer ticks. Main Camera or what? @Nothing'ButNet Apps

Comment: No problem! I can't say I know what the best practice is. It shouldn't really matter, aside from organization. Sometimes I attach it to the main camera and sometimes I make a empty gameobject just to store scripts.